# Using \input for command arguments

Tags: macros, input, external-files, arguments

I'm making an rpg system. I want to separate the contents of the spell from the formatting of the spell to, for example, be able to format the spells differently for character sheets vs a dedicated spell document, or whatever.

I'm trying to use a separate file that has arguments for a formatting macro (\spell) arranged in a predefined fashion that then would get inputed into the document.

This is what I tried.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\spell}[4]{
\noindent   \textbf{#1}
\\  \underline{#2}
\\  \textit{#3}
\\  #4
}

\newcommand{\info}{
{SPELL NAME}
{MANA COST}
{CASTING TIME}
{DESCRIPTION}
}

\begin{document}
    \input{spells/spell template.tex}

    \spell{spell name}{mana cost}{casting time}{description}

    \expandafter\spell\info

%   \expandafter\spell\input{spells/spell template.tex}
\end{document}
```

spells/spell template.tex contains

```latex
{Spell Name}
{Mana Cost}
{Casting Time}
{Description}
```

The first three tests I have in this file work perfectly fine but when I try to uncomment the fourth one latex crashes. I have read that `\input` isn't expandable but I haven't seen any solutions that would solve this problem. This post looked promising but seems to be outdated (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282602/301785). Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: A simple workaround would be, to write the command `\spell` directly into the file. Maybe you have later another version of that command, and then it would also be useful to differentiate from within the single files.

Comment: @dexteritas if `\spell` is only a single example for a formatting macro and there are others, this does make sense to decouple.

Comment: @Skillmon Ah, I see. Then you don't need to redefine the command.

Comment: Yeah `\spell` is only one example.

Comment: Just a random note: If you intend to use files programmatically you should avoid spaces in file names. Those tend to result in interesting behaviour of ad-hoc scripts and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need the behaviour to pick arguments from a file for more than just `\spell`, the following defines a helper macro `\FromFile` that takes as first argument the code after which the file contents should be inserted, and as second argument the file path.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{spell_template.tex}
{SPELL NAME}
{MANA COST}
{CASTING TIME}
{DESCRIPTION}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\spell}[4]{%
  \noindent   \textbf{#1}
  \\  \underline{#2}
  \\  \textit{#3}
  \\  #4%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { amit } { file-not-found }
  { File~ #1~ not~ found.~ RPG-element~ not~ defined! }
\NewDocumentCommand \FromFile { m m }
  {
    \file_get:nnNTF {#2} {} \l_tmpa_tl
      { \exp_last_unbraced:Nno \use:n {#1} \l_tmpa_tl }
      { \msg_error:nnn { amit } { file-not-found } {#2} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\info
  {%
    {SPELL NAME}%
    {MANA COST}%
    {CASTING TIME}%
    {DESCRIPTION}%
  }

\begin{document}
    \input{spell_template.tex}

    \spell{spell name}{mana cost}{casting time}{description}

    \expandafter\spell\info

   \FromFile\spell{spell_template.tex}
\end{document}
```

If treating leading and trailing spaces is important, one could use the following variant:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{spell_template.tex}
{SPELL NAME}
{MANA COST}
{CASTING TIME}
{DESCRIPTION}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\spell}[4]{%
  \noindent   \textbf{#1}
  \\  \underline{#2}
  \\  \textit{#3}
  \\  #4%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { amit } { file-not-found }
  { File~ #1~ not~ found.~ RPG-element~ not~ defined! }
\NewDocumentCommand \FromFile { m m }
  {
    \file_get:nnNTF {#2} {} \l_tmpa_tl
      { \use:e { \exp_not:n {#1} \tl_trim_spaces:o \l_tmpa_tl } }
      { \msg_error:nnn { amit } { file-not-found } {#2} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\info
  {%
    {SPELL NAME}%
    {MANA COST}%
    {CASTING TIME}%
    {DESCRIPTION}%
  }

\begin{document}
    \input{spell_template.tex}

    \spell{spell name}{mana cost}{casting time}{description}

    \expandafter\spell\info

   \FromFile\spell{spell_template.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you this was perfect!

Answer (score 5):

LaTeX hides TeX primitive `\input` into the control sequence `\@@input`. You can set the equivalent command `\primitiveinput` by:

```
{\catcode`\@=11 \global\let\primitiveinput=\@@input}
```

and then you can say

```
\expandafter\spell\primitiveinput{spells/spell-template.tex}
```

**Edit**: the accepted answer implements a `\FromFile` macro which tests in the given file exists. I can show such a implementation using OpTeX just for comparison

```
\fontfam[lm]

\def\spell#1#2#3#4{1:#1, 2:#2, 3:#3, 4:#4}

\def\FromFile#1#2{%
    \isfile{#2}\iftrue \ea#1\input{#2}%
    \else \opwarning{File "#2" not found, \string#1 not executed}\fi
}

\FromFile\spell{template.tex}

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is similar to the one wipet gave. The idea is to use the primitive meaning of `\input`. With  XeTeX or LuaTeX you can use the `\primitive` primitive for that (in pdfTeX it is called `\pdfprimitive`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{spell_template.tex}
    {SPELL NAME}
    {MANA COST}
    {CASTING TIME}
    {DESCRIPTION}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\spell}[4]{
    \noindent   \textbf{#1}
    \\  \underline{#2}
    \\  \textit{#3}
    \\  #4
}

\newcommand{\info}{
    {SPELL NAME}
    {MANA COST}
    {CASTING TIME}
    {DESCRIPTION}
}

\begin{document}
    \input{spell_template.tex}
    
    \spell{spell name}{mana cost}{casting time}{description}
    
    \expandafter\spell\info
    
    \expandafter\spell\primitive\input spell_template.tex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant which attempts to take care of spaces and other things in the file trailing the four arguments.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{template.tex}
{SPELL NAME}
{MANA COST}
{CASTING TIME}
{DESCRIPTION} Something that gets ignored.
Something that gets ignored, too.
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\spell}[4]{%
  \par
  \noindent\textbf{#1}\\%
  \underline{#2}\\%
  \textit{#3}\\%
  #4%
}%

\newcommand\spellGetArguments[4]{\spellRemoveToEndOfLine{\spell{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}}%
\newcommand\SpellSwitchEndlinecharcategory{\catcode\endlinechar=12 }%
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup%
  \@ifdefinable\spellRemoveToEndOfLine{%
    \long\def\spellRemoveToEndOfLine#1#2^^M{\endgroup#1}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\spellinput[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\SpellSwitchEndlinecharcategory
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endinput
  \expandafter\spellGetArguments\@@input"#1" %
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\spellinput{template.tex} Space.

\bigskip

\spellinput{template.tex}NoSpace.

\end{document}
```

[image]